# How to Defuzzify in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Can anyone help me with Centroid defuzzification in Matlab please? What is the value of x in the defuzz code?

output= (x,mf,"Centroid");
What is x here?
If possible give me example please.

Answer (score 0):

I think these links will help you:

---

1. [defuzz](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/defuzz.html)
2. [Defuzzification Methods](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/examples/defuzzification-methods.html)

---

*I hope this helps. Best regards.*